# Lambda subnet setting to fetch the access to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have two pair of `Lambda and Gataway`, one `ECS` and one `RDS`

`Lambdas` and `ECS` needs to access `RDS`

My first idea is put everything in `Public`, because this is the test server, so I want to make it cheap as possible.

However, lambda requires to be put in Public for internet access.

So I made the private isolated subnets then put lambda in `Private Isolated`

However when accessing from `Lambda` to `RDS`, it got stuck and timeout ( it access to the secret manager and then RDS)

My idea is wrong? or what subnets should I set??

```
Lambda - Private Isolated
ECS - Public
RDS - Public
```

Comment: If your rds in same vpc as lambda, you don't need internet connection to access rds. Can you please post vpc and security group details?

Comment: Why does your AWS Lambda function need Internet access?

Comment: I found that the problem is not `RDS` it got stuck when lambda getting key from `secret manager`